# Can you develop themes and plugins while using the hosting services BlueHost?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, theme-development

Can you develop themes and plugins while using the hosting services BlueHost?

Basically are you able to develop on the website such as a plugin or change the php while using bluehost or do you have to locally change the php and then send the new site to BlueHost?

Will I have capabilities of editing php in real time in BlueHost for one of the three basic pricing tiers?

BlueHost is something I am considering for hosting wordpress sites. Is it worth it? As in the 5 dollars hosting per month plan?

Comment: Shouldn't you should ask BlueHost? I don't see why you wouldn't, but even if you do it's bad practice because you can easily bring your site down if you make a mistake.

Comment: I already tried blue host support. They have not responded yet it's been over a week. Please do not down vote due to me asking about bluehost even though they did not respond. Thank you.

Comment: Also I agree bad practice to develop on a live site. It was just a question if bluehost would allow that capability.

Comment: Look I'm sorry if BlueHost is not responsive, but that doesn't make your question relevant to this forum. Hence the downvote. Please refer to the list of questions that would be considered on-topic: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to create a local test WP environment, you could create a second WP site at your hosting place. Just put it in a subfolder of your main site, as in www.example.com/devsite . Develop code (themes/plugins/etc) on that site, and test it on that site. If you want live data, you can 'clone' your main site initially to the dev site. Lots of plugins allow you to do this (I like "WP Clone" from Automatic.)

Create/modify code with your local computer editor, then upload it to your test site at your hosting place for 'almost-live' testing. Once you have the theme/plugin the way you want, install it on your live site.

"Purists" might argue that it is best to have a local WP system for development. But the above way works OK too, without the hassle of maintaining a local WP development site.

I have personally used BlueHost/JustHost for many of my WP sites for many years. My sites are not high-volume/high-visitors, and letting someone else take care of the server back-end processes is an advantage, IMHO. I use the above process for developing my plugins.